# how to find cpu cores used by sql instance in cmd

Tags: sql-server, windows

I dont have access to Management studio, but i want to check how many cores are used by a SQL instance, How to find it without Management studio.

I had tried using

```
select scheduler_id,cpu_id, status, is_online 
from sys.dm_os_schedulers where status='VISIBLE ONLINE'
```

for the servers which I have access to management studio.

Comment: Physical CPU cores or logical (hyperthreading)? Is it a physical server or virtual machine? Some context on _why_ you need the processor count would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of SQL Server tracking physical processor cores, but it can be calculated using the logical `cpu_count` and `hyperthread_ratio` values returned from [sys.dm_os_sys_info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175048.aspx).

The below query was taken from [Glenn Berry's diagnostic queries](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/category/diagnostic-queries/):

```
SELECT cpu_count AS [Logical CPU Count],
       hyperthread_ratio AS [Hyperthread Ratio],
       cpu_count/hyperthread_ratio AS [Physical CPU Count]
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info WITH (NOLOCK) OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have wmi access, you can get this from the win32_processor class. Here's a quick powershell script that (at least in my limited testing) seems to work.

```
(get-wmiobject -query 'select * from win32_processor' | Measure-Object).count
```